# Do all generic types implement the Copy trait?

Tags: rust

Do all generic types in Rust implement the `Copy` trait? To expand upon this, are there a lot of types in the standard library that implement this trait, other than that of generic types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do all generic types in Rust contain the `Copy` trait?

No. That's why you have to explicitly request that a generic type implement `Copy`:

```
fn foo<T>(value: T)
    where T: Copy,
{
    // ...
}
```

> are there a lot of types in the standard library that implement this trait,

[See for yourself](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). A trait's documentation lists its known implementors.